# Efficient way to quit Apps/process on OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, awk, grep

Which would be the best way to quit apps by app name on OS X?

Either I can use Apple script

```
NSString *scriptSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"%@\" to quit",processName];
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource];
[script executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Else I can go ahead with NSTask to execute ps command, do grep and awk to retrieve pid of the process and then quit the process using pid, like what is given below.

```
ps aux | grep -v grep |grep <process name> | awk '{print $2}'
```

In this case I end up using NSTask 4 times + 1 more time to kill the process.

Which is more efficient in terms of performance?

Comment: What about `killall`?

Comment: post the output of `ps aux | grep -v grep |grep <process name>`

Comment: This `ps aux | grep -v grep |grep <process name> | awk '{print $2}'` can be shorten to: `ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess name/ {print $2}'` removing both `grep`.  Using `[]` around first letter in process name, removes the `grep` search from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to  `xargs` command like below.

```
ps aux | grep -v grep |grep <process name> | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

OR

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | awk '/process name/{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

This would kill all the 4 processes.

Comment: You do not need the `grep -v`, just use: `ps aux | awk '/[p]rocess name/{print $2}' | xargs kill`  (adding `[]` around first letter of process name, does exclude the `grep` itself)